# Length of a Parabolic Curve

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

I just wanted to know how I can find the length of a curve given by $f(x) = x^2$ from $x=0$ to $x=1$.

For appproximation, the length is a bit larger than the hypotenuse of isosceles right triangle with the shorter side being 1 long.  It's definitely less than the sum of two shorter sides.  Thus, if we represent the length by $L$, the following relationship is expected:
$\sqrt 2 < L < 2$

I now regard $L$ as the accumulation of hypotenuses of infinitestimally small right triangles around $f(x)$.  Since $f'(x)=2x$, the general right triangle is something like this:
If $x$ goes very slightly down the $x$-axis ($\Delta x$), the the $y$ value goes upwards for $2x\Delta x$.

Thus the hypontenuse is the square root of the following:
$(\Delta x)^2+(2x\Delta x)^2$.
The hypotenuse is:
$(\Delta x) {( 4x^2 + 1)^{1/2}}$

Since $L$ has been defined as the accumulation of these hypotenuses, it is:
$L = \int_0^1 ( 4x^2 + 1)^{1/2} dx$.

I am stuck just here.  Could someone tell me if my chain of thoughts so far is right and how I can go from here?  I don't know how to calculate the integral of a function that contains another function in it.

Thanks!!

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: Thanks, Julian.  I was at a loss how to use LaTeX notations around here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your train of thought is exactly right; you've single-handedly rederived the formula for the length of a curve given by $y=f(x)$ :-) This can be written as

$$
L=\int_a^b\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}\,\mathrm dx
$$

in general. In your case, as you rightly determined, $f'(x)=2x$, and we want the length from $a=0$ to $b=1$, so we have

$$
L=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+4x^2}\,\mathrm dx\;.
$$

To solve this integral, you can use the substitution $\sqrt{1+4x^2}=\cosh u$, so $x=\frac12\sinh u$ and $\mathrm dx=\frac12\cosh u\,\mathrm du$, to get

$$
L=\frac12\int_0^{\operatorname{arcosh}\sqrt5}\cosh^2 u\,\mathrm du=\frac14\left[x+\sinh x\cosh x\right]_0^{\operatorname{arcosh}\sqrt5}=\frac14\left(\operatorname{arcosh}\sqrt5+2\sqrt5\right)\approx1.479$$

If you don't know how to solve such an integral, you can always ask [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+sqrt%281%2B4x%5E2%29+); it will usually know the answer and can often tell you the steps to get there if you click on "step-by-step solution"; though the solution will sometimes, as in this case, not be the most simple one.

You might also be interested in the question [Intuition behind arc length formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27914/intuition-behind-arc-length-formula).

Comment: I read the argument by Arturo Magidin over and over. Yes, that expresses what I wanted to do in a far better way.  $cosh$ and other hyperbolic functions are still mystery to me.  Is there a good starting point in these forums?

Comment: @amemus: I don't know about a starting point in this forum. I would try to understand them by exploring the analogies with the trigonometric functions, e.g. $\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix}=\cos x+\mathrm i\sin x$ vs. $\mathrm e^x=\cosh x+\sinh x$ and $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$ vs. $\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x=1$ -- you can get these and more like them by viewing the hyperbolic functions as trigonometric functions evaluated at imaginary arguments.

Comment: @joriki:  Looks like a typo. The term $\arccos\sqrt5$ doesn't make sense, does it? There is no angle whose cosine is $\sqrt5$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the arc length formula, $$\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+(f')^2}\ dx = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+(2x)^2}\ dx =\left[\frac 1 2 x\sqrt{4x^2+1} + \frac 1 4 \sinh^{-1}(2x)\right]_0^1 \approx 1.479$$

Comment: In my humble opinion, it's not the most encouraging response when the OP has effectively managed to derive the arc length formula all by her- or himself to just tell them "use the arc length formula".

Comment: I'm really sorry, I didn't mean it.

Answer (score -3):

height of parabola=1

base=1

hypotenuse length (check1) = 1.4142135623730950488016887242097

area between parabola and hypotenuse = $(1 \times 1)/6$

parabola length=$\sqrt(( 1\times1 + 1 \times 1 + 1 \times 1)/6) = 1.4719601443879744757940071211599.$

Comment: The answer is very close to the true length of $1.479…$