# Need help with a certain integral

Tags: definite-integrals, quadratics

Sorry, this is my first post ever and formatting is bad. I appreciate all assistance

Given the equation
   y= $ 3.8x^2-4.4x+1444 $
Find the definite arc length integral between 0 and 1200.

I am not sure on how to format $(\frac {dy}{dx})^2$ ,so I left it alone.

$$\int_0^{1200} \sqrt{1+ (\frac{dy}{dx}})^2 dx$$

Comment: I think this ought to read $y=3.8x^2-4.4x+1444$  As it is, your equation  has two complex solutions (no real solutions)...it does not define a curve.

Comment: OH my I am so sorry. I knew I would mess up the formatting. It is fine now, right?

Comment: Your formatting is fine!  Can you solve the problem from here?  $\frac {dy}{dx}$ isn't hard to compute.

Comment: $(7.6x-4.4)$. My issue is I dont know how to expand the integral with the square root.

Comment: Good. Can you compute $\int \sqrt {1+x^2} dx?

Comment: To be clear:  that integral is doable, but it isn't exactly easy.  Here's a discussion of the "arclength of a parabola" issue...not hard to adapt to your situation:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229642/length-of-a-parabolic-curve

Comment: Indeed it does, though as I say it gets you to an integral which, while standard, is not straightforward.  It's unintuitive....I think one would expect the parabola to have a straightforward arclength.  Mind you, things like ellipses are even worse.

Comment: Is there any website or place you recommend that I can learn such derivatives? I haven't really dealt with hyperbolic functions in high school yet.

Comment: You can avoid the hyperbolic functions.  Use the substitution $z=tan(z)$.  That gets you to $\int sec^3(z) dz$.  Have you done that one yet?  Here is a fairly clear discussion:  http://hubpages.com/education/How-to-Integrate-Sqrt-1-x2-Sqrt-a2-x2

Comment: Final question. How many pages would this take to solve and explain?

Comment: I think the link I just sent pretty well does it...so I'd say about one page.  The integrals of  $sec(x)$ and $sec^3(x)$ are worth studying, they do tend to come up.

Comment: So the equation I put up in the question would be one page right? :)

Comment: Absolutely.  You can do it in less if you assume your audience knows $\int sec^3(x) dx$ (or if you are willing to simply write down the solution for that without discussion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same spirit as David G. Stork'answer, consider the general case of $$y=ax^2+bx+c$$ $$\frac{dy}{dx}=2ax+b$$ So $$L=\int \sqrt{1+ (\frac{dy}{dx})^2}\, dx=\int \sqrt{1+ (2ax+b)^2}\, dx$$ Now, make a change of variable $$2ax+b=t \implies x=\frac{t-b}{2 a}\implies dx=\frac{dt}{2 a}$$ So $$L=\frac{1}{2 a}\int \sqrt{1+t^2}\,dt$$ Again, a standard change of variable $$t=\sinh(z)\implies dt=\cosh(z)\,dz$$  $$L=\frac{1}{2 a}\int \cosh^2(z)\,dz=\frac{1}{2 a}\int \frac 12 \left(1+\cosh(2z)\right)\,dz=\frac{1}{4 a}\left(z+\frac 12 \sinh(2z)\right)$$ Back to $x$, this gives $$L=\frac{(2 a x+b)\sqrt{1+(2 a x+b)^2} +\sinh ^{-1}(2 a x+b)}{4 a}$$

Comment: The final derivative is the indefinite, right? If so, do I need to calculate boundaries, or can I simply use $F(b)-f(a)$ to calculate the length?

Comment: Yes to the question. You have $L(x)$ and so the arc length is $L(b)-L(a)$

Comment: Oh sorry for asking this a bit late. Why change t into $sinh$? why not $tanh$? Or why not any other expression? Sorry, I am not well educated on hyperbolic functions and when to use them. In the future, when should input a hyperbole and when shouldn't I ?

Comment: @Michael. When I see $\int \sqrt{1+t^2}\,dt$, I always think about $t=\sinh(z)$ but, as you say, we could have used $t=\tan(z)$ for the same reason. In such a case, $$L=\frac{1}{2 a}\int \sec ^3(z)\,dz$$. If you want me to continue the calculations, let me know.

Comment: The goal of substitution is to arrive to simpler expressions to be integrated.

Comment: Integration by parts in also part of the story in many cases. Again, the goal of substitution is to arrive to something simpler for which we almost know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Take the derivative and plug into your integral and use the fact that

$\int \sqrt{1 + (a + b x)^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt{(a+b x)^2+1} (a+b x)+\sinh ^{-1}(a+b x)}{2 b}$.